# Application Insights dependencies not shown

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

After that my Application Insights Map shows my dependency calls from yesterday i don't see any dependencies in the map and no calls in the analytics page.
I haven't changed my app. Even my page visits aren't on the application map.
What can be the reason that i don't see this part and only my rest api is logging?

Comment: ok I think it was a missing config file in my deployment

Comment: Hey if you figured out the issue, you could post your solution for others to benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the **only** in your bin folder exists the application.config file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not configured your application to use ApplicationInsights
[Set up Application Insights for your ASP.NET website](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net)

Also check if your dependency is up to date. It is currently in version 2.4, so you can use the following features:
[Live Metrics Stream](http://Https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-live-stream)